# I am attempting to pull out short description using sku code and Mage::getModel('catalog/product') in ajax and it isn't working

Tags: attributes, catalog

```
            $product_sku = $mpn; 
        $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product_id = $obj->getIdBySku( $product_sku );
        $_product = $obj->load($product_id); // this is the problematic line
```

The above code is in a ajax controller. I am attempting to pull in the short description using the. The sku is fine and the product id is fine. The problem occurs when we get to $obj->load($product_id). The page load times out when I include this line though I have read numerous tutorials which instruct you to use this same sequence of methods. I thought that it might be because some of the products don't have a short description?? The next stage would be to use $_product->getShortDescription() but I can't get any further. I have tried everything I can think of. Has anybody got any ideas on why this is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try simply loading the attribute raw value. Firstly you need the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product`, then you need to get the product id from the sku and then you can load the store specific value.

```
$resourceModel = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');
$productId = $resourceModel->getIdBySku('your-product-sku');
$attributeValue = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the product directly by the attribute:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'my-product-sku');
echo($_product->getShortDescription());
```

Comment: enzo - $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'my-product-sku'); worked successfully. $_product->getShortDescription() just returns a boolean so i just did $_product->shortDescription which worked. thanks for the help.